# How to smooth scroll with ngAnimate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, ng-animate

I am wondering why inside my controller this does not work:

```
angular.module('app', [
        'ngAnimate',
    ])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $window, $document) {
        var scrollTop = 200 // For example
        angular.element(document).find('body').animate({scrollTop: scrollTop}, 'slow');

    });
});
```

I am just trying to scroll smoothly to a specific offset to the top of the body tag. Do I have to use the `ngAnimate` in a different way?

> **TypeError:** angular.element(...).find(...).animate is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngAnimate` does not have anything to do with `.animate()`. This function is related to jQuery and not to AngularJS. So a working solution will look like this:

```
angular.module('app', [
        'ngAnimate',
    ])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $window, $document) {
        var scrollTop = 200 // For example
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollTop}, 'slow');

    });
});
```

> Also do not forget to load jquery in your html file before you load the script above.